How would you interpret the quantum limit cycle represented by the Wigner function?
This paper by Arosh et. al. discusses the emergence of limit cycles in the quantum phase space (the Wigner function) for nonlinear oscillators.

(The quantum limit cycle of the quantum RvdP oscillator in the semiclassical limit, depicted with the nonnegative Wigner function. The yellow solid line shows the classical limit cycle. The red dashed line shows the Wigner function maximum. I made this with QuTiP.)
Here is an interesting property. In the semiclassical limit—where the quantum equations (approximately) reproduce the classical equation—the classical limit cycle coincides with the Wigner function maximum.
My first thought is that, "Well, this is nothing strange. The classical limit cycle coincides with the most probable part of the Wigner function. So, the quantum limit cycle is just the classical limit cycle getting spread out by quantum noise (i.e. the Heisenberg uncertainty principle)."
However, after reading through the phase space formalism literature, I conclude that my initial thought is nonsensical since the Wigner function can not be a true probability distribution due to the uncertainty principle. The Wigner function maximum may not be interpreted as the most probable part of the quantum limit cycle.
I have also read questions on this site regarding Wigner functions (such as this one), and concluded that the Wigner function by itself means nothing more than the phase space representation of the density matrix. There is no telling about physical quantities without taking phase space integrals or some Moyal products. I have tried taking the marginal of the Wigner function by integrating over $p$ to get the $x$ probability distribution, but nothing interesting can be found there. The most probable position has no clear relation to the classical limit cycle radius and is (unsurprisingly) peaked near the origin for the quantum limit cycle I present above.
In any case, the coincidence between the classical limit cycle and the peak of the Wigner function intrigues me, and I am curious about how the community interprets this.

Wigner functions are not probability distributions, but engender expectation values of observables just like bona-fide probability distributions, so their peaks inform such, as most of the literature, including the paper you are understanding, observe. Your paper discusses this in its conclusions. What is your actual question not covered by a careful reading of said question?

And what does "engender expectation values of observables" mean here? Both $\left\langle x \right\rangle$ and $\left\langle p \right\rangle$ are zero for the quantum limit cycle I show thanks to the circular symmetry, yet the Wigner function coincides with the classical cycle which shows nonzero $x$ and $p$. The $x$ and $p$ marginal give $0$ expected values, but then again this does not tell me anything about the coincidence.

The conclusion says, 'It should be emphasized that
the Wigner functions that describe all the limit cycles are
“essentially classical,” developing no negative regions for any
choice of parameters'. Nonnegativity aside, what does being "essentially classical" mean here? I know that coherent states rotate in the phase space under $\hat{H}=\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}$ in which case the notion of phase point is kept by the peak of the coherent state's Wigner function. Does it mean that the limit cycle "behave classically" in analogue to how a coherent state does in the above case?

x and p are not the only observables; in fact, here, they are far less informative than $x^2+p^2$ and their powers. I assume you have appreciated all examples and their precise meaning here?

So by "engender", you mean I can "roughly guess" what limit cycle radius to expect simply by looking at the quantum limit cycle? Indeed, now that you mention it, $\left\langle\sqrt{\hat{x}^2+\hat{p}^2}\right\rangle$ is nonzero and seems to be a weighed average over a set of "limit cycle radius-es" whose most probable value coincides with the classical limit cycle! And most probable need not be the average---the expected limit cycle radius is somewhere inside the "fuzzy ring" but is generally not at where the Wigner function peak is.
